# Unity3D - Screen Capture of particular UI elements

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, screenshot

How can I screenshot particular UI elements?

In my case I need screen capture UI Panel with child objects like UI Text, UI Input and etc.

Please take a look at picture. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: @fafase has provided a correct answer, please mark answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know the dimensions of the box to be copied. Then you pass the values to the ReadPixels method

```
float width = boxWidth;
float height = boxHeight;
float x = boxXPosition;
float y = boxYPosition;    
var tex = new Texture2D( 1, 1, TextureFormat.RGB24, false );
tex.ReadPixels( new Rect(x,y,width,height), 0, 0 );
tex.Apply();
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.ReadPixels.html